# Handling OS X library data type difference between minor versions when submitting to Mac App Store

Tags: macos, app-store, versioning

I have an app written for Mac OS X in the Mac App Store. The application uses libnetsnmp, whose version has changed between OSX 10.11.1 and 10.11.2 from 5.6 to 5.6.2.1. One result of this change is that the `oid` data type, defined in the lib headers, has also changed from `uint32_t` to `u_long`, and as the result of that, the app stopped working correctly on OSX 10.11.2. Please note, the exact details of the change are not that important to the question I'd like to ask.

I was wondering how to deal with an issue like the one above with regards to submitting an app to the Mac App Store. I would like to keep the app compatible with earlier versions of OS X, but also work on the latest one. As far as I know, there's no provision for having two binaries available on the Mac App Store, one for the latest OS X and the other one for previous releases.

I think using my own data type (e.g. via `typedef`) depending on which version of the OS the app has been compiled on won't work either, as those are used during the compilation and the app will be compiled on the OSX 10.11.2. I would need to use the right data type (`uint32_t` or `u_long`) during runtime.

This would be a bit easier if the change happened between major OS releases, as I could have just made the newer version of the app compatible with the newer version of the OS using the Deployment Target settings in Xcode, but this only allows me to set the major release.

### The two questions

So the question I have is: How do you deal with a case when an underlying lib changes a data type between minor OS X versions and you still want to keep the app compatible with older releases of the OS?

Is it possible to restrict the newer version of the App to only be available for OS X 10.11.2 and newer? In that case, at least I won't break the App for users on older releases of the OS when I publish the update.

### EDIT: Two possible solutions

#### Solution 1

As per the answer provided by Cristik, one solution is to manually type in the minimum deployment target field the major and minor version of the os (in this case, 10.11.2), which should make the updated version of the App, including the required changes for the new data type in the newer version of the library, available on the Mac App Store only to users who run OSX 10.11.2 or newer.

#### Solution 2

Another way, which has an added benefit of not relying on the library version included with the OS, is to bundle my own version of the library with the app.

In this case, I've downloaded the source code of the net-snmp library (I used version 5.6.2.1) and compiled it outside of Xcode. I then installed it in a directory somewhere inside my homedir - I used the `--prefix=/Users/myusername/devel/Frameworks/usr` option for `configure` script included with libnetsnmp.

In Xcode, I then went to Build Settings, found Search Paths section, and changed two settings:

- Always Search User Paths: YES
- User Header Search Paths: add `/Users/myusername/devel/Frameworks/usr/include`

Then in Build Phases, in Link Binary With Libraries, remove the `libnetsnmp.dyld` bundled with the OS, click on the `+` sign and add the `libnetsnmp.dyld` from `/Users/myusername/devel/Frameworks/usr/lib`.

Finally, in Build Phases / Copy Files, add `libnetsnmp.dyld` from `/Users/myusername/devel/Frameworks/usr/lib` with the Destination set to Frameworks. I also have the Code Sign On Copy set to Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the second question, you can set the deployment target for the new app version to the minimum OSX version that works. Users with older OSX versions will get the current store app, while the other users will get the new version.

Regarding the first question, this one is a little bit trickier, as you'll kinda need to maintain in parallel two branches of your app: one with the old library, and one with the new library. Not sure how this suits the AppStore design though, as you cannot upload two binaries when submitting an update for your app. It might be that users with older OSX-es will need to get stuck to the latest version of the app that used the old library.

Comment: Regarding your answer to my second question - this was going to be my first approach, but unfortunately it won't work if the incompatibility was introduced between two minor versions (10.11.1 and 10.11.2), as I think you can only specify the deployment target as a major version (e.g. 10.10 or 10.11, not 10.11.1 or 10.11.2). Thanks anyway!

Comment: You can set 10.11.2 as deployment target. It's not in the dropdown list, but you can type it manually.

Comment: I didn't know that. I'm going to accept this as an answer, as that will sort out the issue I have. I also figured out another way which is to bundle my own version of the lib with the application - I'll add the description of the required steps to my original post. Thanks!